# formatting xsd validation message in java

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, stax

when an xml is validated against a XSD schema using javax.xml.validation.Validator class following type of error messages are displayed.

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'LastName'. One of '{FirstName}' is expected.

cvc-pattern-valid: Value '12345x67890' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[0-9]{10}' for type 'PhoneType'.
```

Is there any way to display user friendly messages than verbose message like above?

For example in the below xml

> 1. if Firstname tag is not passed then error should be "Firstname is required in Employee element" isntead of "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Lastname'. One of '{Firstname}' is expected."
> 2. If phonenumber is entered as '12345x67890' then error should be "Invalid value for Phonenumber in Employee element" instead of
>      "cvc-pattern-valid: Value '12345x67890' is not facet-valid with
>      respect to pattern '[0-9]{10}' for type 'PhoneType'."

```
<Employee>
<Firstname></Firstname>
<Lastname></Lastname>
<PhoneNumber></PhoneNumber>
<Salary></Salary>
</Employee>
```

Following is the java code I used to validate xml against schema

```
    String schemaLang = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    XMLStreamReader reader = null;
    try {
        Validator validator =
            SchemaFactory.newInstance(schemaLang).newSchema(new StreamSource(xmlschemastream)).newValidator();
        reader =
            XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString.trim())));
        validator.setErrorHandler(new XsdErrorHandler(reader));
        validator.validate(new StAXSource(reader));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

XsdErrorHandler.java

```
public class XsdErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private XMLStreamReader reader;

    public XsdErrorHandler(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader; }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
          throw new SAXException(reader.getLocalName());}

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw new SAXException(reader.getLocalName());}

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException sAXParseException) throws SAXException {}
}
```

Solution I used-

```
final List<String> exceptions = new LinkedList<>();     
validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                        exceptions.add(exception.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                        exceptions.add(exception.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {

                        String message = exception.getMessage();
                        if (message.contains("cvc-type.3.1.3") || message.contains("cvc-complex-type.2.4") ||
                            message.contains("cvc-elt.1")) {
                            String[] errors = message.split(":");
                            errors[0] = "";
                            String required = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                                required = required + errors[i];
                            }
                            exceptions.add(required);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: javax.xml.validation.Validator is an interface, not a class, so the answer depends on which implementation you are using. I can tell you how to go some way to achieving this requirement with the Saxon implementation of javax.xml.validation.Validator, but I won't do that unless you ask for it.

Comment: I ma using default implementation provided by JRE not any third party implementation.

Comment: @springbatcher were you able to figure out the solution for user friendly error message for xsd validation message? I have the same problem too, please let me know if you have a solution

Comment: @RanPaul there's no direct solution available. I wrote my own custom message formatter based on String operation to format messages and display the same.

Comment: @springbatcher could you please provide me ur message formatter, I'll customize it for my use case

Comment: Updated question with solution used, it captures necessary messages into a list and then process each String messages based on few key words by using a property file which maintains keys and expected message incase of that keyword found in XSD validation message.